# How to add target="_top" only if validation succeeds in Spring MVC?

Tags: forms, redirect, spring-mvc

I just want to jump out of an iFrame to _top after my registration form is submited an the validation succeeded. I easily can add target="_top" to the form, but than the validation after submit will jump out of the iFrame, too.

Is there a way to just add the top-target to the final modelAndView (e.g. "redirect:http://google.com")?

Cheers